# How to fully suppress an error when invoking powershell with a command?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to write an msbuild postbuild event that will copy a file. It need not be 100% - the destination file might be used or locked in which case I would like the build to succeed.

so I have something like*

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "cp foo `$(TargetDir)"
```

when `$(TargetDir)\foo` is used by another process I get an error and my build fails. So I try

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "cp foo `$(TargetDir) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"
```

yet the error is printed and it fails. So I try

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "try { cp foo `$(TargetDir) } catch {}"
```

and now the error is not printed yet it STILL fails because if I execute the above `$LastExitCode` still equals 1.

I can wrap yet again in try catch and powershell but how do I suppress the error correctly?

---

*The actual command is the following - not that it matters

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"try { ls '`$(SolutionDir)\packages\GhostScriptSharp.*\Tools\gsdll32.dll' | Sort -Descending | Select -First 1 | cp -Destination '`$(TargetDir)' } catch {}`""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `exit` keyword to set the script's exit code explicitly:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "cp foo `$(TargetDir) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; exit 0"
```